# String increment: increment the last string by one

Tags: javascript, regex, string, numbers, increment

the purpose of this code is to to write a function which increments a string, to create a new string. If the string already ends with a number, the number should be incremented by 1. If the string does not end with a number the number 1 should be appended to the new string. e.g. "foo123" --> "foo124" or "foo" --> "foo1".
With my code below, pretty much all my test cases are passed except a corner case for "foo999" did not print out "foo1000". I know that there should be a way to do with regex to fix my problem, but I am not too familiar with it. Can anyone please help?

```js
function incrementString (input) {
  var reg = /[0-9]/;
  var result = "";
  if(reg.test(input[input.length - 1]) === true){
    input = input.split("");
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if(parseInt(input[i]) === NaN){
            result += input[i];
        }
        else if(i === input.length - 1){
            result += (parseInt(input[i]) + 1).toString();
        }
        else{
            result += input[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
  }
  else if (reg.test(input[input.length - 1]) === false){
    return input += 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: your function is too complicated, you should use the `replace` method with a lambda as replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function pad(number, length, filler) {
    number = number + "";
    if (number.length < length) {
        for (var i = number.length; i < length; i += 1) {
            number = filler + number;
        }
    }

    return number;
}

function incrementString (input) {
    var orig = input.match(/\d+$/);
    if (orig.length === 1) {
        orig = pad(parseInt(orig[0]) + 1, orig[0].length, '0');
        input = input.replace(/\d+$/, orig);
        return input;
    }

    return input + "1";
}
```

What does it do?

It first checks if there is a trailing number. If yes, increment it and pad left it with zeros (with the function "pad" which you'd be able to sort it out yourself).

`string.replace` is a function which works with argument 1 the substring to search (string, regex), argument 2 the element to replace with (string, function).

In this case I've used a regex as first argument and the incremented, padded number.

The regex is pretty simple: `\d` means "integer" and `+` means "one or more of the preceeding", which means one or more digits. `$` means the end of the string.

More info about regular expressions (in JavaScript): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp (thanks @Casimir et Hippolyte for the link)

Comment: Fixed! Now it checks only for the last characters being a digit and, in case, it adds "1" at the end of the string if it wasn't found any :)

Comment: Omg, you guys are awesome! Let me check the code and get back to u if I have any questions :)!!

Comment: The code basically passed the corner case except, it didnt pass this test:
 "foobar000"---> "foobar001"

Comment: @Someone anubhava's solution has the very same problem, so why accepting his now? In any case, added the padding thing, so that `foo000 -> foo001`.

Comment: @Someone: From where did this new requirement of 0001 to 0002 had come? Was it part of your question?

Comment: it was an ex. i did on codewar, it passed that test with my old code, but it didnt pass the one that i was asking.
But anyway, i already completed it, thanks for helping out :) 
and i read both you guys' reply and it really helps me a lot. Its really hard whoever i should accept/choose you two (because you guys are great!)
I hope no one would feel upset by whoever i accepted, I really enjoy the enthusiasm of your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace with a callback:

```
'foo'.replace(/(\d*)$/, function($0, $1) { return $1*1+1; });
//=> "foo1"
'foo999'.replace(/(\d*)$/, function($0, $1) { return $1*1+1; });
//=> "foo1000"
'foo123'.replace(/(\d*)$/, function($0, $1) { return $1*1+1; });
//=> "foo124"
```

**Explanation:**

```
/(\d*)$/                # match 0 or more digits at the end of string
function($0, $1) {...}  # callback function with 2nd parameter as matched group #1
return $1*1+1;          # return captured number+1. $1*1 is a trick to convert
                        # string to number
```

Comment: This doesn't take in consideration strings like `1foo1`

Comment: @Jack: True, but the OP didn't mention needing to handle those. The bigger problem with this answer is that it doesn't explain anything, it just gives the man a fish without *teaching* him to fish.

Answer (score 1):

The most concise way that also accounts for leading zeros, non-numeric endings, and empty strings I've seen is:

```
''.replace(/[0-8]?9*$/, w => ++w)
//=> 1

'foo'.replace(/[0-8]?9*$/, w => ++w)
//=> foo1

'foo099'.replace(/[0-8]?9*$/, w => ++w)
//=> foo100

'foo999'.replace(/[0-8]?9*$/, w => ++w)
//=> foo1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your code greatly:

```
function incrementString(input) {
    var splits = input.split(/(\d+)$/),
    num = 1;
    if (splits[1] !== undefined) num = parseInt(splits[1]) + 1;
    return splits[0] + num;
}
```

This checks for any number of digits at the end of your string.

Comment: FYI, the past tense of "split" is "split", not "splitted" (I'd say it's an irregular verb, but there are so many styles of verbs in English it could easily be the regular form of some style).

Comment: You should initialize `num` with 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: correct, I didn't read the requirements thoroughly.
@T.J.Crowder: Thanks for this hint - `splitted` is not a good variable name. `split` isn't either :-)
I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function incrementString (strng) {
      //separateing number from string
        let x = (strng).replace( /^\D+/g, '');
      //getting the length of original number from the string
      let len = x.length;

      //getting the string part from strng
      str = strng.split(x);

      //incrementing number by 1
      let number = Number(x) + 1 + '';

      //padding the number with 0 to make it's length exactly to orignal number
      while(number.length < len){
        number = '0' + number;
      }

    //new string by joining string and the incremented number
      str = (str + number).split(',').join('');
      //return new string
      return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My quick answer will be :

```
let newStr = string.split('');
let word = [];
let num = [];
for (let i = 0 ; i<string.length ;i++){
  isNaN(string[i])? word.push(string[i]) : num.push(string[i]) 
}
let l=num.length-1;
let pureNum=0;
for (let i = 0 ; i<num.length ;i++){
  pureNum += num[i] * Math.pow(10,l);
  l--;
}
let wordNum = (pureNum+1).toString().split('');
for (let i = wordNum.length ; i<num.length ;i++){
  wordNum.unshift("0");
}
return word.join("")+wordNum.join(""); 
}
```

Comment: A bit of explanations is welcome because your code without comments is not very instructing